# Setting an HTML element as scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css

Working with a lightbox effect at the moment. The problem is my lightbox has a lot of text inside it. Problem is, I cant figure out how to make a scroll function inside so the user can scroll down the element.

**CSS**

```
/* Lightbox background */
#lightbox {
  display:none;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  min-width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  z-index:1000;
}
/* Lightbox panel with some content */
#lightbox-panel {
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  top:100px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-200px;
  width:400px;
  background:#FFFFFF;
  padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;
  border:2px solid #CCCCCC;
  z-index:1001;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a#show-panel").click(function(){
    $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeIn(300);
  });
    $("a#close-panel").click(function(){
    $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeOut(300);
  })
});
```

[My example](http://jsfiddle.net/9LFKV/148/)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I tried overflow: scroll; but that did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked on this and what you needed for your situation is just have it to position fixed.. Get rid of that and it should work..

CSS code:

```
    body{
  margin:150px 0 0 0;
  text-align:center;
  background: #f1e7b0;
}
h2{
  font-size: 32px;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Lightbox background */
#lightbox {
  display:none;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  min-width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  z-index:1000;
}
/* Lightbox panel with some content */
#lightbox-panel {
 display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-200px;
  width:400px;
  background:#FFFFFF;
  padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;
  border:2px solid #CCCCCC;
  z-index:1001;
}
#lightbox-panel{
    overflow: scroll;
}
body{
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

**Link** : http://jsfiddle.net/9LFKV/158/

### Fixing background color

To fix the background color, i just attached a $.css({}) in the JS File and it worked :D. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a#show-panel").click(function(){
    $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeIn(300);
        $('html').css('background-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)')
  });
    $("a#close-panel").click(function(){
    $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeOut(300);
  })
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9LFKV/162/)

Comment: Ah ye that does work , but do you see the background colour? it disappears at the bottom

Comment: Happy Coding @RonTheOld . Just one reccomendation for you. I was a previous jQuery Master. But then made the swich to Go Lang. Trust me Go is an awesome Lang. So when you get the time research about Go. And [here](http://www.golang-book.com/books/intro) is an awesome book made by a great author! Sorry for bieng so random.. Its a desease of mine. Again Happy Coding!

Comment: I think changing the background color of the HTML object only works if there are no other objects that the lightbox is covering. The correct answer is to swap the positioning attributes for the #lightbox and the #lightbox-panel, as in the answer that I posted.

Comment: Hmm..... There are many ways to solve coding... @mcissel .. there is no "correct" way

Comment: I'm saying that changing the HTML is wrong, because it only works if the lightbox is longer than the rest of the content. This answer is wrong.

Comment: Add a longer div, id="white". With css: "
#white {
  height:5000px;
  width:350px;
  margin: 0 50px;
  background-color:white;
}"

Comment: I signed up and made a fiddle to show the problem: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcissel/p5gqqbfb/1/). Notice that if you set the #lightbox position to fixed it DOES work. Sometimes, @Amanuel, there is a correct way.

Answer (score 1):

You had the position attribute for the lightbox (background) and the lightbox-panel switched. They should be:

```
#lightbox-panel {
  ...
  position:absolute;
  ...
}
```

and

```
#lightbox {
  ...
  position:fixed;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#lightbox-panel {
position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Ah ye that does work , but do you see the background colour? it disappears at the bottom